# DHCP failed on wlan0 (keep getting 169.254.x.x addresses)

Tags: pi-2, networking

I am trying to set my Pi2 to have DHCP allocated IP for its USB WiFi dongle. However, everything it got was a 169.254.x.x (169.254.155.42) IP address. Setting static IP works somehow, but with some other problems.
Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

auto wlan1
allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

The `wpa_supplicant.conf` looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="My_SSID"
    psk="My_Wifi_password"
    #proto=RSN
    #key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    #pairwise=CCMP
    #auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

The `dhcpcd.conf` is unmodified.
Can you give me some suggestions to find out the source of problem?
Thanks.

Comment: The file you have posted has multiple errors and will not work. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697 for tutorial

Comment: I have already tried the method of using wpa_supplicant for wlan0:

[
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
]

as stated in the link, but the result was the same.

Comment: @Milliways I tried out the exact settings of the tutorial again and edited the post accordingly (this was actually where I came from) and the problem was why I kept on experimenting different settings.

Comment: The `169` address is `link-local` - it is what happens before allocation. Have you tried using GUI? You need to confirm that the WiFi Dongle (You give no details) is detected and has a driver. Assuming this is OK `dmesg` should show attempt to connect.

Comment: @Milliways thanks for prompting me to do a dmesg which led to some more fruitful search.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I found the root cause of the problem:

The WiFi USB dongle was not fully supported: it has a Realtek RTL8191S WLAN chipset and although it was fully recognized and even the static IP somewhat worked, DHCP was not fully supported. Some other people ran into similar problems with the same dongle:
http://www.forum-raspberrypi.de/Thread-csl-wlan-usb-stick-funktioniert-nicht

I did an rpi-update to update the firmware and then after reboot, I amended the /etc/network/interfaces file back from static IP to using DHCP allocated IP, and everything worked for almost 2 whole days. And then it stopped working again after some other software package updates and installation I performed. :\

Comment: It stopped working again - after 1-2 day of consistently working in multiple rebooting, I just installed something trivial (e.g. apache2, php5, MySQL, emacs' elpa), Pi2 is getting only 169.254.x.x address again. However, I definitely can see my Wifi network with a $sudo iwlist wlan0 scan, with 100/100 signal level. This keeps me badly scratching my head.

Comment: try `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` if you adapter supports power management schemes it will turn off the wifi after some days of working.